# dotenv-webpack cannot load env varibles on production

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, dotenv

What I'm trying to do is set up env varibles as CRA but using webpack. I have created two env files like what CRA does. `.env.development` and `.env.production`. These two files are working in CRA. And I'm using `dotenv-webpack` inside `webpack` config file to set the `process.env` varibles as below code. It's working on the localhost, but not on production.

```
const Dotenv = require("dotenv-webpack")
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"

//webpack config
modules.exports = {
...
 plugins: [
        new Dotenv({
            path: `./.env.${isProduction ? "production" : "development"}`,
        }),
 ...
 ]
...
}
```

on `package.json`, I use:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack serve"
}
```

So I can get the corret `isProduction` varible on webpack.

Can anyone help me fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `.env` files should never be pushed on your git repo. So specifying a path is useless. You should enter these variables directly in your docker config, or in Netlify/Heroku's env variables area. Then to make your dotenv plugin work in production, just add:

```js
new Dotenv({ systemvars: true }),
```

Comment: No, I don't use Heroku. I put react built file into AWS S3 directly so what I can only do is upload the built files. I will push a env-sample instead of .env.production and .env.development on git repo.